# How to check whether ear is deployed correctly in weblogic 12c?

Tags: deployment, war, ear, weblogic12c

I have an application ear which I am trying to deploy into `Oracle Weblogic 12c` server. I following instructions given on [this](http://onlineappsdba.com/index.php/2008/08/12/deploy-application-on-oracle-weblogic-server/) site.

After following those steps, I tried to hit the url "http://localhost/myApp/servlet" where `myApp` is specified in `application.xml` file and `servlet` is specified in `web.xml` file. This web.xml file is located with the `.war` file and this war file is within the `.ear` file.

My `application.xml` looks like below :

```
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/application_1_4.xsd" version="1.4">
  <description>This is my application</description>
  <display-name>myApp</display-name>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>myApp.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/myApp</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
</application>
```

and my `web.xml` looks like as below :

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.foo.bar.MyServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>servlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

When I hit the url on browser, I get 404 (Not Found) error. I am trying to deploy any ear/war on weblogic 12c for the first time so I do not know what is going wrong. I checked server logs too, but there's no stack trace or error.

Request you to please help !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your Admin Console and you can see if the deploy is deployed correctly.
In NetBeans IDE you go do Services > Servers > Oracle Weblogic Server > right click on Oracle Weblogic and select **View Admin Console**.

Them you have to login you session and in the menu on left side of your screen, you have deployment. In this part you can see if the deployment is correct.

I hope this will help you.